# How do I sync 'monero.exe' and my wallet?

Tags: synchronization

I just installed the monero package from monero.org and I set up a wallet. Now I'm running 'monerod.exe' and the wallet, but it says that they're not synced together... How do I fix this?

Comment: Inlcude actual error messages. "it says that they're not synced together" is not helpful.

Comment: Wait for it to sync? It takes a while.

Comment: monero.org is not a trusted website. If you downloaded anything from there, I suggest you remove it and use getmonero.org instead, which is the canonical site for monero.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that monerod is completely synced with the network. You will know when monerod.exe prints something on the screen along the lines of "Monerod is now synchronized with the network. You may now start monero-wallet-cli."

2) Start monero wallet. After it loads up, type in "refresh." It should then show you something like "Height xxxxxx/xxxxxxx". Once it is done syncing with monerod, it will show you your balance.

Please post if this helped you and if it didn't what happened.